# ERROR: Wrong number of arguments to #<procedure

Tags: scheme

When I run the following piece of code, I encountered an error:
    **ERROR: Wrong number of arguments to #cartesian (x)>**

;;;; function definition

```
(define (eps-func p)
   (let* ((p (lattice->cartesian))
         (x (vector3-x p))
         (y (vector3-y p))
         (z (vector3-z p)))
        (if (> sin(* 2 pi x y z) 0)
            (make dielectric
                    (epsilon 12))
            (make dielectric
                    (epsilon 1)))))
```

;;;; function call

```
(set! default-material (make material-function (material-func eps-func)))
```

I cannot figure out where it is wrong. The above code is only part of a control file.

Some background information is as following:

```
(lattice->cartesian x)
```

where x is a vector3

vector3 is a datatype defined somewhere

3-vector functions

```
(vector3 x y z)
```

Create a new 3-vector with the given components.

```
(vector3-x v)
(vector3-y v)
(vector3-z v)
```

Return the corresponding component of the vector v.

material-func [function]
A function of one argument, the position vector3

Comment: Why the downvotes, without any comments, guys?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should invoke `(lattice->cartesian))` with parameter? Or this function returns lambda?

Comment: I've got some response from Scheme mail list. Like flamingo said, there should be a parameter for function call lattice->cartesian, and it reads like the following.
(define (eps-func p)
       (let* ((p (lattice->cartesian p))

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like there are two errors here. First off @flamingo already has mentioned, but to make it clear I rename the let-bound variable so that it is different from the argument. In addition I added missing parenthesis around sin.

```
(define (eps-func p)
   (let* ((tmp (lattice->cartesian p))
         (x (vector3-x tmp))
         (y (vector3-y tmp))
         (z (vector3-z tmp)))
        (if (> (sin (* 2 pi x y z)) 0)
            (make dielectric (epsilon 12))
            (make dielectric (epsilon 1)))))
```

I have tested it using dummy procedures and it seems to work. Hope it helps.